# Cucumber step definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I am using Cucumber/Capybara to write some feature level tests.

Here is my feature definition

```
Feature: User Signin
  As a User
  I want to signin
  So i can use my app

  Background:
      Given user with "email" email and "password" password

  Scenario: Signing in with correct credentials
      When I go to sign in page
      And I fill in "user_email" with "email"
      And I fill in "user_password" with "password"
      And I click "Sign in" button
      Then I should go to the dashboard page
```

How do i define the step to check if it went to a specific page? Basically how do i define the following step?

```
Then(/^I should go to the dashboard page$/) do
end
```

Also is there a documentation for Cucumber/Capybara step definitions?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

1. Check page's path/url using [`current_path`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session#current_path-instance_method) or [`current_url`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session#current_url-instance_method) methods:

   ```
   Then(/^I should go to the dashboard page$/) do
     current_path.should == expected_path
     # or current_path.should == expected_url
   end
   ```
2. Check contents of the page using one of [RSpec matchers](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers)

   ```
   Then(/^I should go to the dashboard page$/) do
     page.should have_css('#id_that_is_present_only_at_dashboard_page')
   end
   ```

Also you may use page object pattern and do something like:

```
current_path.should == DashboardPage.path
```